# Luis Suarez goalscoring record.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, inclusion-exclusion

> **Problem:**
>
> The $2013-14$ season was a short-lived ray of hope in an otherwise long dark night for the world’s greatest football team. The team played $38$ league games and the main contributing factor to the success was Luis Suarez $31$ goals.
>
> $(i)$ Suarez was suspended for the first five games of the season after having bitten a Chelsea player the previous spring.
>
> $(ii)$ The most goals he scored in a game was four, and this he achieved once.
>
> $(iii)$ He scored two goals on six occasions.
>
> How many possibilities does this leave for his goalscoring record ?

---

**Solution:**

Suarez played $33$ games.

There are $\binom{33}{1}$ choices for the
game in which he scored four goals.

Then there are $\binom{32}{6}$ choices for the six
games in which he scored two goals each.

This leaves $26$ games and we know that

$(a)$ He scored $0,1$ or $3$ goals in each of these games.

$(b)$ He scored a total of $31−4−2 \cdot 6 = 15$ goals in these $26$ games.

We seek the number of solutions to

$x_1 + \cdots + x_{26} = 15, \:\:\:\: x_i \in \{0,1,3\}$

We do a case-by-case analysis:

**Case $1$**: He scored $3$ goals five times and $0$ goals every other time. There are $\binom{26}{5}$ choices for the goalscoring games.

**Case $2$:** He scored $3$ goals four times, $1$ goal three times and $0$ goals otherwise. There are $\binom{26}{4}\binom{22}{3}$ choices for the goalscoring games.

and so on...

Putting it all together, using the multiplication and addition principles, the number of possibilities for his goalscoring record is

$$\binom{33}{1}\binom{32}{6}\left[\binom{26}{5} + \binom{26}{4}\binom{22}{3} + \binom{26}{3}\binom{23}{6} + \binom{26}{2}\binom{24}{9} + \binom{26}{1}\binom{25}{12} + \binom{26}{15} \right]$$

$$\approx 2.5521 \times 10^{16}$$

Is there are more efficient way to solve this problem and other similar problems where the constraints can be even more challenging? E.g. how would you use generating functions which is suggested in the comments?

Comment: The problem statement is incorrect. Suarez never played for the world's greatest football team.

Comment: Try using generating functions.

Comment: @DanielFischer Never? He did play for Ajax in the past. Once upon a time (in the days of Johan Cruijff, R.I.P.) that was the world's greatest football team.

Comment: "Assume an adult mouth contains 32 teeth. In how may ways could Suarez leave a combination of incisors, molars and canine teeth marks on your neck?"

Comment: @drhab Never. Ajax is great, and at times was the best, but the greatest football team fielded Bobby Charlton and George Best.

Comment: @DanielFischer Hehe, I have to agree with that Daniel! :)

Comment: @Batman Yes, that might be the way to go. I have not learnt much about generating functions in combinatorics yet.

Comment: @DanielFischer The Mancunians are great! But..., no, let me not try to convince you. A good look at myself makes clear how useless that is :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using inclusion-exclusion. The number of ways of distributing $15$ goals over $26$ games such that $2$ goals were scored in $k$ particular games and at least $4$ goals were scored in $l$ particular games is

$$
\binom{15-2k-4l+26-k-1}{26-k-1}\;,
$$

so the desired count is

$$
\binom{33}1\binom{32}6\sum_{k=0}^7\sum_{l=0}^3(-1)^{k+l}\binom{26}k\binom{26-k}l\binom{40-3k-4l}{25-k}=\binom{33}1\binom{32}6\cdot853423740\;,
$$

in agreement with your calculation.

Comment: @JKnecht: I'm afraid I don't have any book recommendations because I learned most of what I know in these areas from this site and Wikipedia; but for understanding this particular answer you might want to look at [Balls In Bins With Limited Capacity](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath337.htm). Note the slightly different role of $k$ and $l$: Whereas a game with at least $4$ goals merely subtracts $4$ from the number of goals to be distributed, without reducing the number of games to distribute them to, a game with exactly $2$ goals also reduces the number of games by $1$.

Comment: So $15-2k-4l$ is the number of goals that remain to be freely distributed, and $26-k$ is the number games to distribute them to.